# Why deleting from a table does not work in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I tried deleting a row from a table but the result was 
DELETE 0

When I created a copy of the original table and performed the delete on the new copy-table
the result was: DELETE 1 as expected

I've created a trigger function that updates a column on a different table upon inserting or deleting is there an option that this is the problem?
Does anyone know what might be the problem ??

P.S. I post a similar to the creation code of the original table because it has been altered for the next parts of the university project and the trigger function's code

P.S.2 A friend who has the same exact database, table, trigger function etc.
doesn't have this problem

```
create table Listings(
   id int,
   listing_url varchar(40),
   scrape_id bigint,
   last_scraped date,
   name varchar(140),
   summary varchar(1780),
   space varchar(1840),
   description varchar(2320),
   experiences_offered varchar(10),
   neighborhood_overview varchar(1830),
   notes varchar(1790),
   transit varchar(1810),
   access varchar(1830),
   interaction varchar(1340),
   house_rules varchar(1820),
   thumbnail_url varchar(10),
   medium_url varchar(10),
   picture_url varchar(150),
   xl_picture_url varchar(10),
   street varchar(90),
   neighbourhood varchar(20),
   neighbourhood_cleansed varchar(70),
   neighbourhood_group_cleansed varchar(10),
   city varchar(40),
   state varchar(60),
   zipcode varchar(20),
   market varchar(30),
   smart_location varchar(40),
   country_code varchar(10),
   country varchar(10),
   latitude varchar(10),
   longitude varchar(10),
   is_location_exact boolean,
   property_type varchar(30),
   room_type varchar(20),
   accommodates int,
   bathrooms varchar(10),
   bedrooms int,
   beds int,
   bed_type varchar(20),
   amenities varchar(1660),
);

    CREATE FUNCTION Vs()
    RETURNS "trigger" AS
$Body$
    BEGIN
        IF(TG_OP='INSERT')THEN
            UPDATE "Host"
            SET listings_count = listings_count + 1
            WHERE id = NEW.host_id;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF(TG_OP='DELETE')THEN
            UPDATE "Host"
            SET listings_count = listings_count -1
            WHERE id = OLD.host_id;
            RETURN OLD;
        END IF;
    END;
$Body$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger
    before INSERT
    ON "Listing"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE Vs();

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteTrigger
    before DELETE
    ON "Listing"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE Vs();
```

Comment: Is the row actually deleted, or not?

Comment: Note: there is an extra comma in your (rather bulky) table definition : `amenities varchar(1660),`

Comment: Also: what is the `DELETE` statement? Do you get a result if you run a `SELECT` statement with the same `WHERE` clause? Are there other triggers on the table?

Comment: @GMB no. @wildplasser it is a typo from the copy-paste. @Laurenz `DELETE FROM "Listings" WHERE host.id = 999 ` (which is a row I added for testing purposes), yes select works fine  and no there aren't any other triggers